# Stalling at deallocate

Tags: fortran

My 2D hydro code stalls during the following subroutine (which computes the y-direction flux):

```
 ALLOCATE(W1d(1:my,nFields),q1d(nFields),&
           Wl(1:my,nFields),Wr(1:my,nFields))

 PRINT *,"Main loop"
 DO i=1,mx
    DO j=1,my
       q1d(1) = qVar(i,j,1,iRho)
       q1d(2) = qVar(i,j,1,  iE)
       q1d(3) = qVar(i,j,1, ivy)
       q1d(4) = qVar(i,j,1, ivx)
       CALL Cons2Prim(q1d(:), W1d(j,:))
    ENDDO

    CALL lr_states(grid, W1d, dt, dy, Wl, Wr, dir)

    DO j=1,my
       Flux(i,j,:) = hllc_flux(wl(j,:), wr(j,:))
    ENDDO

    DO j=1,my
       CALL Prim2Cons(Wl(j,:),Ul(i,j,:))
       CALL Prim2Cons(Wr(j,:),Ur(i,j,:))
    ENDDO
 ENDDO
 PRINT *,"Deallocating"

 DEALLOCATE(W1d,q1d,Wl,Wr)
 PRINT *,"Returning"
```

I separated the `DEALLOCATE` statement into 4 separate statements and found that whichever 2D array would come first, `W1d`, `wl`, or `wr`, was the cause of the stall. Ignoring the `DEALLOCATE` statement (which should produce an automatic deallocate when going back to the main) also causes a stall. The subroutine for the x-direction flux has the same arrays, is called before this subroutine, and has no problems deallocating them.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT** This is run on Fedora 18 and compiled with Intel Fortran 2013.3. It is a parallelized code, but I am running it on a single processor for testing/debugging purposes.

Comment: Bizarre stuff like this happens to me once in a while. I don't have any advice from the top of my head. But I would suggest adding full compiler and CPU information in your question. You never know, someone might help. Is this possibly an MPI job, and only some processes are calling this routine?

Comment: Updated with information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did three different things and it suddenly started working again. Two of them I do not believe could have done it, while it is possible the third did it. The changes I made:

- I did have the bounds of `i` and `j` loops defined slightly differently, so I made it uniform between the two directional sweeps
- I ran `make clean` and `make`
- I added `-check bounds -check pointers -check uninit` flags to the Makefile

I think the first two did not really do anything. The variable `grid` in the code above is a 2x2 array that contains the bounds of `qVar`; in the x-sweep I had defined `mx = grid(1,2) - grid(1,1) + 1`, similarly for `my`, but grid(1,1) **is** 1, so it really does not do much different. The second item above I had done at least 3 times.

But the last one I tried once and it started working again. I do not know how that could have fixed it, so if someone does know, please tell me!