# Deallocate Statement Causes Crash

Tags: windows, gcc, fortran90, gfortran

I am working on a code that is crashing. I realized that the compiled program crashes when it is deallocating the variables, but I don't know how to fix it.

When I run the code, a pop-up from Windows appears saying:

`main.exe has stopped working.
Windows can check for a solution to the problem.`

and the compiler shows the message `Process returned -1073740940 (0xC0000374)   execution time : 1.171 s`

Bellow there is a sample of the code:

```
Subroutine PoissonCode()
Use Mesh
Implicit none
Real(8), Allocatable :: u(:,:),v(:,:),p(:,:)
Character(50) :: Nome
Allocate(u(0:Imax,0:jmax),v(0:Imax,0:jmax),p(0:Imax,0:jmax),fx(0:Imax,0:jmax),fy(0:Imax,0:jmax))
Allocate(xd(0:Imax),yd(0:Jmax))

........Code Here...............

Deallocate(u,v,p,fx,fy,xd,yd)
Deallocate(xd,yd)

End Subroutine PoissonCode
```

I put the complete code [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24478877/Code.zip) for further investigation.
I also tried to run the code with different versions of GFortran in Windows 7 x64 and Windows XP x86 with no success.

**Edit:**

The correct end of the code is:

```
...

Deallocate(u,v,p,fx,fy)
Deallocate(xd,yd)

End Subroutine PoissonCode
```

**Up date:**

I tested the code with a different compiler (Intel Visual Fortran) and still no success.

Comment: A **System** crash? As in a [BSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death)? If not, please don't claim so.

Comment: I put `pause` statement before and after `deallocate`. This allows me to conclude that deallocating is probably the reason of the crashes.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I had a similar issue not too long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452243/stalling-at-deallocate.

Comment: Thank you Kyle, I did that and now the compiler is saying `attempt to DEALLOCATE unallocated 'xd'`. But it is allocated!!! What is wrong with it? Do you think it is because `xd` comes from a Module?

Comment: One thing I notice is that even removing `Deallocate` statements the `main.exe has stopped working` problem still happens when `PoissonCode` subroutine returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'uhhhh (to all of us)

```
Deallocate(u,v,p,fx,fy,xd,yd)
Deallocate(xd,yd)
```

In the second line your program (attempts to) deallocate variables already deallocated in the first line.  I suppose that sometimes it pays to read code posted.

`deallocate` has optional arguments `stat` and `errmsg` which can be used to catch this sort of mistake and provide an alternative to the default behaviour which is for the program to crash.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, but I typed this by mistake here when I was formulating the question. My original code does not have this double Deallocated variable. I tried to use the optional arguments you mentioned but the code stalls before I am able to see the error parameters.

Comment: OK... I found the error. The code inside subroutine `PoissonCode` was accessing an invalid array position. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Yes, looking at your code again, you have `p(0:imax,0:imax)` in the subroutine `PoissonSolve` but declared it `p(0:imax,0:jmax)` in the `PoissonCode` subroutine.